# Use libc++ standard library implementation on GCC instead of libstdc++

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang

I'm trying to use the LLVM's standard library implementation (libc++) on GCC trunk (version 12.0.0 now) for the purpose of using the Formatter Library, which is implemented only in libc++ at this time (except MSVC). For this, I tried to compile with g++ in the following way:

```
g++ -std=c++23 -nostdinc++ -nodefaultlibs -I<path-to-libc++>/include/c++/v1 -I<path-to-libc++>/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/c++/v1 example.cpp -lc -lc++ -lc++abi -lunwind
```

Location for the dynamic libraries is specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH environment variables on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Distro.

Code inside example.cpp is the following:

```
#include <format>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = std::format("{}", "Hello");
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

If I use clang-15 for this purpose, it compiles successfully and the command for compiling with clang is the following:

```
clang++ -std=c++2b -stdlib=libc++ example.cpp
```

With GCC, the code is unable to compile because of the following errors (not all):

```
a.cpp:(.text+0x837): undefined reference to `vtable for std::__1::format_error'
/usr/bin/ld: a.cpp:(.text+0x847): undefined reference to `std::__1::format_error::~format_error()'
/usr/bin/ld: a.cpp:(.text+0x84c): undefined reference to `typeinfo for std::__1::format_error'
```

I'm asking if that's something wrong with the GCC command that I use or what can be the reason of this from the 2 compilers sides (g++ and clang).

Comment: You can check if it is supported with `__cpp_lib_format` [feature test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/feature_test) of the [formatting library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format).

Comment: I'm not even sure GCC is compatible with libc++. If you want string formatting, use https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Comment: Have you tried the command given here: <https://releases.llvm.org/14.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#using-a-custom-built-libc>. Seems like `-rpath <path-to-libc++>/lib` to the linker might fix this

Comment: @Eljay It seems that __cpp_lib_format is commented in version header file, but I don't know exactly why. As I said, with clang it compiles and I can run the executable and prints what I expected. I checked also the __availability header file and it defines _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_FORMAT and the line with #define _LIBCPP_AVAILABILITY_DISABLE_FTM___cpp_lib_format is commented out.

Comment: @Artyer I tried also the -rpath, but I get the same error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm not sure too, that's why I asked it here.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem is that the library path need to be explicitly added with `-L` GCC option, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LIBRARY_PATH` didn't work in this case, but not sure why.